# Spring boot: disable logger

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-logback

This is my `application.properties` under `_/config` folder:

```
logging.file=logging.xml
```

This is the content of `_/config` folder:

```
$ tree config  
config
├── application-bo.properties
├── application-loc.properties
├── application-pre.properties
├── application.properties
├── application-pro.properties
└── logging.xml
```

The content of `logging.xml` is:

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

    <!-- LOG "com.baeldung*" at TRACE level -->
    <logger name="net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.common.dao.RedisDao" level="OFF" additivity="false" />
</configuration>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to disable logs generated inside from `net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.common.dao.RedisDao` logger.

However, I'm getting log messages on console yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: `logging.file` is the name of the file to write the logging to. it is NOT the configuration file. To disable the logging just add `logging.level.<package-here>=NONE` or the likes to the `application.properties`.

Comment: Aint' able to set spring-boot picks for a custom `custom-logback.spring.xml` configuration file?

Comment: Not by using the property you are using, and what you want to achieve can be done without an additional xml file.

Answer (score 0):

What you are configuring only applies for file appender.

Have you tried defining the console appender and just add your specific configuration for the console?

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.common.dao.RedisDao" level="OFF" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general in spring boot you can edit the `application.properties` (or yaml) file and define series of definitions for logging, including levels.

This means however that you don't really need to create `logging.xml` file - spring boot will configure logging only out of the definitions found in the `application.properties/yaml` file:

```
logging.level.net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.common.dao.RedisDao=OFF
```

One note about `logging.file` which is just wrong:
If you're configuring loggging via properties/yaml file - you can use this property to specify the output file name where the logs will be written (its like configuring file appender directly in older applications).

If you really want to maintain the XML file, its possible, them you can create: `src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml` file and put the definitions there.
Again in this case you don't need any properties at the level of `application.properties` (including `logging.file` property).

Here is an example of such an approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">
   <logger name="net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.common.dao.RedisDao" level="OFF"/>
   <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
   <jmxConfigurator/>
</configuration>
```